# Grep: Recursive option produces unexpected behavior when fed pipe-input

Tags: unix, grep, pipe

I've been using this utility successfully for many years, in many environemnts. But I'm noticing that on one particular environment, it produces very unexpected results.

```
grep -r 'search-term1' . | grep 'search-term2'
```

The above code greps recursively for all instances of search-term1, in the current-dir. The results are then piped to another grep, which selects only those lines that also contain search-term2. This works exactly as I would expect.

```
grep -r 'search-term1' . | grep -r 'search-term2'
```

The only difference in the above code is that the -r recursive flag in specified in both grep commands. I would expect the behavior to not change for this particular case. After all, the input to the 2nd grep is a pipe-input, and there's nothing further to be found recursively.

I have been using the command successfully, for many years, in many different environments (both unix and mac-os). However, the most recent environment that I started working in (unix), breaks the above behavior. The second piped grep searches for all instances of search-term2, not only in the piped-input, but also all files in my current directory. Because of this, instead of getting only results that contain both search-terms, I get all results in current-dir that contain the 2nd search term.

Is there any reason why this one particular environment produces this odd behavior? Is there any way I can avoid this, while still preserving the -r flag?

---

FAQ:

Q: Why am I using the -r flag on a piped input?

Ans: I actually have grep saved as an alias, with many different options and flags that I always want to use as a default. The recursive flag is one of them. I would like to always use this alias, instead of having to type out all the flags every time.

Q: If you want to search for all instances matching both search terms, why not do (insert-superior-method-here) instead?

Ans: You're probably right. I'm sure there are things I can change in my usual habits that would workaround this issue. However, as intellectual curiosity, I would like to find out why recursive-greps-on-pipes work as intended on most environments, but not all, and if that can somehow be resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-r` flag to grep changed in grep version 2.11 ([release notes](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7132) to implicitly use the working directory as the input if no file arguments are given.

> If no file operand is given, and a command-line -r or equivalent
>     option is given, grep now searches the working directory.

You aren't giving the second `grep` any file arguments so it defaults to the current directory despite there being pipe input.

Try `grep -r 'search-term1' . | grep -r 'search-term2' -` as a workaround.

`grep -r 'search-term1' . | grep -r -d skip 'search-term2'` may also work around the problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clarification and link.

Regarding grep_options, apparently it has been deprecated, and they now recommend using an alias instead.

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3343